# Remove PIL from raspberry Pi

Tags: jpeg, python-imaging-library, uninstallation, raspberry-pi

Hi i am getting an error
"IOError: decoder jpeg not available" 
when trying to implement some functions from the PIL.
What i would like to do is remove PIL, install the jpeg decoder then re-install the PIL, but im lost as to how to uninstall the PIL?
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this to re-install PIL

pip install -I PIL